# Save First name and Last name of customer in Capitalize format

Tags: database, controller, prestashop-1.6

I have Prestashop 1.6 and I am trying to save first name and last name of customer in capitalize format in database.  so its will look good every where e.g PDF, emails etc

current

jamil ahmed

Target

Jamil Ahmed

I have achieve this with CSS and jQuery but its only working on front-end and not saving it in database so it will work everywhere as I need.

Can any expert guide me which file or  classes,temple or controller I need to edit so when ever user create account or update his information then first name and last name will save in capitalize format.

Thanks
I hope Its not difficult for experts

Answer (score 0):

You can override Customer.php with this file saved under `/override/classes/Customer.php`:

```
<?php
class Customer extends CustomerCore 
{

    public function add($auto_date = true, $null_values = false)
    {
        $this->firstname = ucfirst($this->firstname);
        $this->lastname = ucfirst($this->lastname);
        return parent::add($auto_date, $null_values);
    }

    public function update($null_values = false)
    {
        $this->firstname = ucfirst($this->firstname);
        $this->lastname = ucfirst($this->lastname);
        return parent::update($null_values);
    }
}
```